# How to nullify the fadeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm actually not sure whether that's the right question to ask. I'm not really sure what the problem is here. But anyhow. 
I'm trying to create a table where each tile shows a random color and then fades away after you mouse over it. Right now I have the ability to change the tile color when I mouse over, but I can't get it to fade away correctly, because when it does fade away, I can't bring any color back after I mouse over it again. How exactly would I get it to start over again after each fade away? Here's what I have for my script for one of the tiles.

```
    document.onmouseover= userMoved; 
    function userMoved(event) {
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    var coords = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y;

    var index = Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
    var ColorValue = "FFFFFF"; 
        if(index == 1)
        ColorValue = "FFCCCC";
        if(index == 2)
        ColorValue = "CCAFFF"; 
        if(index == 3)
        ColorValue = "A6BEFF"; 
        if(index == 4)
        ColorValue = "99FFFF"; 
        if(index == 5)
        ColorValue = "D5CCBB"; 
        if(index == 6)
        ColorValue = "99FF99";
        if(index == 7)
        ColorValue = "FFFF99"; 
        if(index == 8)
        ColorValue = "FFCC99"; 
        if(index == 9)
        ColorValue = "CCCCCC";
    if (x>100 && x<201 && y>100 && y<200){
        document.getElementById("row1column1").style.backgroundColor = "#"+ColorValue;
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#row1column1").mouseleave(function(){
            $("#row1column1").fadeOut();
        });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ? , create stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Comment: Can you make this in a JSFiddle that includes your html?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){` you don't need it in your function

Comment: you fadeOut the element, but when do you fadeIn the element ? 
You should also optimize your "if", use an array instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that .fadeOut() decreases the opacity until it reaches 0, at which point the element's display is set to none. (and opacity is reset to 1).

Your element needs to have its display reset when you match your onmouseover condition

```
document.getElementById('row1column1').style.display='';
```

Comment: While this works, sometimes if I mouseover the tile too quickly, I get an error that says "Cannot read property 'style' of null". Is there any fix for that?

Comment: Could you post a working fiddle or at least some html?